# PHPMailer gives no errors but email stuck in Queue

Tags: php, iis, smtp, phpmailer

I have a form that uses PHPMailer to send the form contents to an email address. Here is the script:

```
<?php

require_once('assets/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->From = "jobform@website.com";
$mail->FromName  =  "Job Form";
$mail->AddAddress("receivingaddress@website.com","Job Form");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

$mail->Subject = "Job Form";
$mail->Body="
            First Name: $first_name
            Last Name: $last_name
            Phone Number: $phone
            Email: $email
            Job: $job";

$maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
$types = array('application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');


if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'] < $maxsize && in_array( $_FILES['fileUpload']['type'], $types)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
} else {

  header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/join-our-team.php");
  echo 'Please upload a PDF or Word Document that is under 2MB';
  exit();

}

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.website.com/join-our-team.php");
      echo 'Please enter a valid email address';
      exit();
}

if($first_name == '') {
      header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.website.com/join-our-team.php");
      echo 'Please enter your first name';
      exit();
}

if($last_name == '') {
      header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.website.com/join-our-team.php");
      echo 'Please enter your last name';
      exit();
}


if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
  header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.website.com/");
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
}

?>
```

When I submit the form I get the success message (Thank you for your feedback.) but an email never shows up in my inbox. My site in running on Windows Server 2012. I have an SMTP server installed and all computers are allowed to relay through the virtual server.

When I check for the inetpub > mailroot > Badmail folder, there are no "bad" emails. Instead, the emails are being saved to the inetpub > mailroot > Queue folder. Does this mean there is a connection problem? Is there a specific smtp setting that needs changed or should I modify my php script?

Comment: Which logs? The emails show up in the queue folder but I don't know which logs to check.

Comment: The logs for the SMTP server. Make sure it's running and forwarding emails.

Comment: If the messages are getting into the queue, your problem is not with PHP, it's with the SMTP server. You should ask for help at serverfault.com, it's not a programming question.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the help. I'll move the question over to serverfault.